# DOMPDF PNG output - multiple PNGs displaying only one PNG with incorrect colours

Tags: php, iis, dompdf

Having some seriously mind-bending problems with DOMPDF's rendering of PNG files.

Using the latest version of DOMPDF according to their Github page, on a Windows IIS server.

---

I have a two-fold problem:

1. PNG images are displaying with a black background and white foreground, regardless of the colours of the images
2. If I use multiple PNG images, all of the images on the page appear as the first image, squashed into different size ratios

Here's a screenshot to explain:

[image: Banner]

Now, if I replace one of the images with a JPEG file, it works:

[image: jpeg]

If I change the first PNG image to be rendered, it displays like this:

[image: Barry]

---

The HTML that I'm using is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>test</title>

        <style type="text/css">

            *{
                color:'.$font.';
                font-family:Helvetica, Arial, Serif;
            }

            .i{font-style: italic;}
            .b{font-weight:bold;}

            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{display:inline;}
            h1{font-size:350%;}
            h3{font-size:275%;}
            h6{font-size:150%;}
            span{font-size:125%;}
            div{background-color:'.$bg.';}

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div align="center" style="margin-left:10px;margin-right:10px;padding:0px;">
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <img src="img/banner/'.$type.'/top.png" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <h1 class="b" style="color:'.$font.';">'.$type.' Certificate</h1>
            <br />
            <br />
            <h3 class="i" style="color:'.$font.';">'.$name.'</h3>
            <br />
            <br />
            <h6 style="color:'.$font.';">This certificate has been awarded to you for earning over '.$points.' points on the LEAP System.</h6>
            <br />
            <br />
            <img src="img/barry.png" />
            <br /><br />
            <img src="img/badge.png" />
            <br />
            <h6 class="i">' . 'Date Awarded: '.date("d-m-Y").'</h6>
            <br />
            <br />
            <span>Awarded by: '.$school.'</span>
            <br />
            <br />
            <img src="img/banner/'.$type.'/bottom.png" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And the PHP code that I'm using to generate the PDF is as follows:

```
public function save($data, $size, $orientation, $name, $type){
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->set_paper($size, $orientation);
    $dompdf->load_html($data);
    $dompdf->render();
    $data = $dompdf->output();

    $filename = 'data/'.$type.'/'.$name.' - '.date("d-m-Y").'.pdf';
    return file_put_contents($filename, $data);
}
```

---

After I generate a certificate, I get the following log in `dompdf\lib\fonts\log.htm`:

```
52 7936.00 KB 1073.05 ms OFF
ï»¿[__construct img/banner/Bronze/top.png][__construct img/barry.png][__construct img/badge.png][__construct img/banner/Bronze/bottom.png]get_min_max_width() auto auto;758.85850393701pt auto;773.85850393701pt auto;1010 121|757.5 90.75;get_min_max_width() auto auto;758.85850393701pt auto;773.85850393701pt auto;115 100|86.25 75;get_min_max_width() auto auto;758.85850393701pt auto;773.85850393701pt auto;187 60|140.25 45;[image:C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\frog\certificate_generator/img/banner/Bronze/top.png|1010|121|3]!!!png!!![addImagePng .png]
Warning: unlink(.png) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\frog\certificate_generator\dompdf\lib\class.pdf.php on line 4046
[image:C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\frog\certificate_generator/img/barry.png|115|100|3]!!!png!!!
Warning: unlink(.png) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\frog\certificate_generator\dompdf\lib\class.pdf.php on line 4046
[image:C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\frog\certificate_generator/img/badge.png|187|60|3]!!!png!!!
Warning: unlink(.png) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\frog\certificate_generator\dompdf\lib\class.pdf.php on line 4046
get_min_max_width() auto auto;758.85850393701pt auto;773.85850393701pt auto;1010 121|757.5 90.75;[image:C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\frog\certificate_generator/img/banner/Bronze/bottom.png|1010|121|3]!!!png!!!
Warning: unlink(.png) [function.unlink]: No such file or directory in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\frog\certificate_generator\dompdf\lib\class.pdf.php on line 4046
```

Does anyone know what might be causing these seemingly bizarre problems?

Comment: This is bizarre. Looks like one of the images is being parsed for it's alpha channel and that's what's being placed, though I can't say why. It's probably a path issue, as you can see from the `unlink()` calls there are some incomplete file names. These errors appear to be internal to dompdf/cpdf, but you might start out by checking the HTML being parsed by dompdf. Call `$dompdf->output_html();` after you load the HTML to see what dompdf is using internally. You also might check the setup page at dompdf/www/setup.php to see if there are any red flags.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this turned out to be because ImageMagick wasn't installed on our server. DomPDF should probably check for its existence before attempting to generate PDFs containing PNG files?

Just for the record, here are the steps I was required to take to install ImageMagick on IIS:

- Uninstall existing imagick installations and DLL extensions from PHP
- Install imagick `ImageMagick-6.6.2-10-Q16-windows-dll` from [here](http://image_magick.veidrodis.com/image_magick/binaries/).
- Add latest version of thread safe (ts) or non-thread safe (nts) dll, for example `php_imagick_nts.dll`, to PHP extension dir from [this link](http://valokuva.org/builds/).
- Add `extension=php_imagick_nts.dll` to php.ini
- Run following cmd command to add IIS permissions to temporary directory: `cacls c:\windows\temp /E /C /G iusr_SERVERNAME:R`

It's worth noting that the last statement may be considered insecure on working installations. You can change the imagick temporary directory in the configuration settings, but personally I couldn't get it working.

Comment: dompdf won't use ImageMagick unless you've enabled the ImageMagick PHP extension. If you haven't installed ImageMagick don't enable the ImageMagick extension.

Comment: Also, you don't need ImageMagick at all. dompdf is able to do its work with just the GD extension. ImageMagick support is provided because it can improve performance around image handling.